# Why form input[type="checkbox"] is considered as readonly by Firefox but it shouldn't?

Tags: forms, firefox, checkbox, readonly-attribute

Firefox considers my form input[type="checkbox"] as readonly but it shouldn't as the field is editable. It works on every other browser including chrome or even IE11.

The code looks like below:
HTML:

```
<input name="upgradeSmu" id="id_fd5049f8-8549-4b0e-8f81-afbfe927d562" type="checkbox">
```

CSS:

```
form input:-moz-read-only, form input:-moz-read-only:hover, form input:-moz-read-only:focus {
  border-color: #dddddd !important;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: not-allowed; }
```

Firefox for some reason considers provided CSS as valid for the input:
[image]

Chrome shows me following:
[image]

Firefox version: 65.0.2.

This can be reproduced with simplest HTML:

```css
form input:-moz-read-only,
form input:-moz-read-only:hover,
form input:-moz-read-only:focus {
  border-color: #dddddd !important;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
        content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="style.css">
  <title>Checkbox test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Form</h1>
        <form id="book-form">
            <div>
                <label for="title">Checkbox test</label>
                <input type="checkbox"
                        checked="true"
                        id="checkbox">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK seems I have found the answer here; Firefox has a bug and I have reported it under:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1532968